Word: Show page numbers to left of entries in Table of Contents
How can I create an automatic Table of Contents in Word in which the page numbers are shown to the left of the entries?  Example:
Page
   1 – Introduction
   3 – First Section
   4 –   First Subsection
  12 – Second Section


You need to use the text direction button on the Home tab to apply to your Table of Contents.

These buttons are only available if you have an East-Asian language such as Arabic enabled on your computer. It does not need to be the language actually applied to anything. Select your TOC and click on the right-to-left button (the one on the right.

This does put the page numbers on the left, but it doesn't left-align the text.  The text then becomes right-aligned.  Is there another setting that will cause the text to left-align?

Another way you could consider doing this is to insert a { PAGE } field at the beginning of each Heading. (E.g. press Ctrl-F9, then type PAGE between the special field code braces {  }. Maybe put a tab after it to help the alignment in the ToC., but you can make it a very small tab.
Then select the field code and apply White Color to the text. Also apply (say) 4pt text size to the field. There are other ways you could reduce the character width if need be. Update all the field codes, then regenerate yout ToC.
The field result will appear as "Auto" color (i.e. typically black) in the ToC. You can modify the ToC styles to alter the tab spacing etc.
Personally I tend to have the right-to-left feature enabled here, but when you enable it, it does introduce a number of new things in familiar dialog boxes that some people might find confusing.
